# How do I convert this nested selectors to LESS?

Tags: less

I am a novice in LESS CSS, but I have spent lot of time learning the CSS. Currently am migrating my CSS code to a LESS for learn and improve myself. I stumbled upon this when am doing the migration process,

**Existing CSS Code**

```
#sidebar {
    -webkit-transition: background 1.2s ease, padding 1.8s linear;
    background: #3c3c3c;
}

#sidebar .actionMenuList {
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}

#sidebar .actionMenuList .topNavMenuList,
#sidebar .navigationMenuList .topNavMenuList {
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
     border-bottom: .1em solid #FDF7F8;
}
```

**Writing this LESS Code**

```
#sidebar {
   -webkit-transition: background 1.2s ease, padding 1.8s linear;
    background: #3c3c3c;

    .actionMenuList {
        margin-bottom: 20%;

        .topNavMenuList {
            -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
            border-bottom: .1em solid #FDF7F8;
        }
    }
}
```

But am getting stuck in one place, how do I write the css prop for the navigationMenuList class  selectors using the above hierarchy. Or do I need to fallback on the usual way of CSS for this

```
#sidebar .actionMenuList .topNavMenuList,
#sidebar .navigationMenuList .topNavMenuList {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do

```
#sidebar {
    .navigationMenuList .topNavMenuList { }    
}
```

all together

```
#sidebar {       
    .actionMenuList {
        .topNavMenuList { ... }
    }
    .navigationMenuList {
        .topNavMenuList { .... }
    }
}
```

OR

assuming the rules are the same for both

```
#sidebar {
    .actionMenuList,
    .navigationMenuList {
        .topNavMenuList { 
            -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
            border-bottom: .1em solid #FDF7F8;
        }
    }
}
```

you can even do

```
#sidebar {
    .actionMenuList .topNavMenuList,
    .navigationMenuList .topNavMenuList { 
        -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
        border-bottom: .1em solid #FDF7F8;
    }
}
```

On a side note, if you ever get stuck at converting and need to make it work. Just leave the css in the less file and it will work like normal.

Comment: @Bharath I didn't copy the css you have for those selectors because there is no point doing so. The idea is very straight forward, you just needed help on how to write the format of it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and does what I expected.

```
#sidebar {
    -webkit-transition: background 1.2s ease, padding 1.8s linear;
    background: #3c3c3c;

    .actionMenuList { margin-bottom: 20%; }

    .actionMenuList .menuItem, .navigationMenuList .menuItem {
        -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
        border-bottom: .1em solid #FDF7F8;
    }
}
```